# Verify switchport port configurations

Tags: regex

I am looking for a shorter form of following commands.  The only variable that changes is the port number but developing the nested loops is where I fall short.  Thanks.

interface FastEthernet1/0/18.*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport access vlan 1002.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport mode access.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security mac-address sticky.*\n(.*\n)*.* shutdown.*\n(.*\n)*.* no cdp enable.*\n(.*\n)*.* spanning-tree portfast

interface FastEthernet1/0/19.*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport access vlan 1002.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport mode access.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security mac-address sticky.*\n(.*\n)*.* shutdown.*\n(.*\n)*.* no cdp enable.*\n(.*\n)*.* spanning-tree portfast

interface FastEthernet1/0/20.*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport access vlan 1002.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport mode access.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security mac-address sticky.*\n(.*\n)*.* shutdown.*\n(.*\n)*.* no cdp enable.*\n(.*\n)*.* spanning-tree portfast

interface FastEthernet1/0/21.*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport access vlan 1002.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport mode access.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security mac-address sticky.*\n(.*\n)*.* shutdown.*\n(.*\n)*.* no cdp enable.*\n(.*\n)*.* spanning-tree portfast

interface FastEthernet1/0/22.*\n(.*\n)*.* description Unused Port.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport access vlan 1002.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport mode access.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security.*\n(.*\n)*.* switchport port-security mac-address sticky.*\n(.*\n)*.* shutdown.*\n(.*\n)*.* no cdp enable.*\n(.*\n)*.* spanning-tree portfast

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I write a nested loop to cover each interface instead of using my current code.